# Django (IIS) deployed, logging issue

Tags: django, logging, iis, http-status-code-500

I deployed django app on IIS, however my logging code that was working perfectly on local host, caused server 500 error...
Can I get any help please?

```
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'loggers': {
        'django': {
            'handlers': ['debuglog'],
            'level': 'DEBUG'
        },
        'django.server': {
            'handlers': ['errorlog'],
            'level': 'ERROR'
        }
    },
    'handlers': {
        'debuglog': {
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'class': 'logging.FileHandler',
            'filename': './logs/debug.log',
            'formatter': 'simple',
        },
        'errorlog': {
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'class': 'logging.FileHandler',
            'filename': './logs/error.log',
            'formatter': 'simple',
        }
    },
    'formatters': {
        'simple': {
            'format': '{levelname} {message}',
            'style': '{',
        }
    }
}
```

Maybe IIS does not allow django to create log files and it needs permission to do so? If this is the case, how would I do that?

Answer (score 0):

you can follow the below steps to deploy the Django site in iis:

1)Add the site with your project root path in iis.

2)Select site-> Doble clcik handler mappings. Click “Add Module Mapping…” from the actions selection on the right.

3)Set request path to * and Module to FastCgiModule.

set executable:

C:\Python39\Scripts\python.exeC:\Python39\Lib\site-packages\wfastcgi.py

4)Now back to the server node and select the fast cgi module.

add below environment variable:

```
DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE = “path to your settings”
WSGI_HANDLER = django.core.wsgi.get_wsgi_application()
PYTHONPATH = “path to your repo-root e.g. C:\inetpub\wwwroot\djangosite”
```

Do not forget to assign iis_iusrs and iusr permission to the site root folder and python folder.

check the log folder permission too.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/python/configure-web-apps-for-iis-windows?view=vs-2019

Comment: Without logging code, it is being deployed well. I have also successfully configured IIS media and static folders. Do I have to configure log folder permissions on IIS? is that the possible issue? I am looking over the link you shared to find how I can configure log folder

Comment: @AleksandreBregadze you just need to right-click on the log folder-> select Properties->Select the Security tab->Click the Edit button and then Add button-> Enter IUSR in the Enter the object names to select: text box.-> Click the Check Names button and click OK.-> Check Full control under the Allow column, and click OK, and OK.assign permission for iis_iusrs user by following the same step.

Comment: @AleksandreBregadze Is your issue solved?

If your issue is solved then I request you to mark the helpful suggestion as an answer. This will help other people who face the same issue.

Comment: Hi, issue is not yet solved. I am looking for solution, when I find it, if nobody before writes it here, I will myself answer the question )